# visual basic writes gibberish at the start of text file

Tags: vb.net, file, text, append

I'm writing numbers in a text file one number in each line like this:

```
N=3
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(file_name, N & vbCrLf, True)
```

If I then read this line with Fortran instead of returning 3 it returns Ύ╗┐3.
And if I read it with Python it returns ο»Ώ3
This only happens at the very first of the file and nowhere else. How do I get rid of it and why it's there?

Comment: That's the UTF-8 preamble. The default encoding, when you use a StreamWriter, is UTF-8. Read the file using the same encoding. Or specify the Encoding, to avoid writing the BOM. Since UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII Encoding, when the BOM is not inserted at the beginning of the file, you have the same result. This of course applies to codepoints in the range (0-127). After that UTF-8 uses 2 bytes per char. But you can simply use Encoding.ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method uses UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM). `Environment.NewLine` is platform independent. Requires `Imports System.IO` at top of file.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim N = 3
    File.AppendAllText(file_name, N & Environment.NewLine)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Jimi didn't notice that he was adding several numbers

Comment: That does work, thanks. Turns out it also works using StreamWriter. Also, I didn't mention in my original question, but the "dangerous" thing about WriteAllText is that the .txt if opened with, say, notepad++ (or even notepad) it showed perfectly fine, only if I read it like I mentioned it shows those first 3 odd characters.

Comment: @Monochromatic Notepad knows about the various file type and byte order markings for Unicode, so it hides them from you.  (Strictly speaking, the so-called byte-order mark for UTF-8 is a misnomer because there is no variation in byte order as the basic unit is a single byte.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `vbNewLine` instead of `vbCrLf`.

```
Dim N As Integer = 3
My.Computer.Filesystem.WriteAllText(file_name, N & vbNewLine, True)
```

This should solve your issue. Or, that problem has a high chance of happening due to text encoding problems.

Comment: I've tried vbNewLine before and I tried it again just in case but didn't help.What about encoding though? I'm not using weird characters, just writing an integer.

Comment: Try writing the file with `System.IO.Filesystem.WriteAllText(file_name, N & vbNewLine, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)` or `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` and see if it works.

Comment: re: vbNewLine  In the MS Docs Warning

This API is now obsolete.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnewline?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How about Environment.NewLine?